# Capistrano: upload via scp failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting an "upload via scp failed" error when I run `cap deploy`, with the following output:

```
  * executing `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes'
...
 ** Updating mtimes for ~8 assets...
 ** scp upload #<StringIO:0x007fca13a94f40> -> /apps/my_app/TOUCH_ASSETS
*** upload via scp failed on <ip>:
*** (
*** )
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

When I ran `cap deploy:cold`, there were no errors.

What is the source of this error and how do I go about debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

In your Capistrano deployments file, you are passing a StringIO to the scp command instead of a file name.  If the StringIO object in question contains the name of the file(s) you wish to copy, then you must convert the StringIO to a string:

```
 stringIOobject.read()
```

Comment: Do you use the `put` or `upload` commands?  If so, paste your code so we can take a peek.

Comment: Seems to be choking on this line in Capistrano itself: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/assets.rb#L95

Comment: I don't use `put` or `upload` in my own deploy.rb

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue and haven't been able to figure out how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your asset manifest file isn't correctly formatted, such as having a typo.  Look in the following manifest files in your project and double check everything.

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

If you have any other custom manifest files be sure to check them out too.  [Look at the examples here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) to make sure the formatting is correct.

Comment: Hmm... Haven't touched those files as it is a starter app with only a "Post" scaffold in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try compile your assets locally and then upload via rsync, like this

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :assets do
    desc "Precompile assets on local machine and upload them to the server."
    task :precompile, roles: :web, except: {no_release: true} do
      run_locally "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
      find_servers_for_task(current_task).each do |server|
        run_locally "rsync -vr --exclude='.DS_Store' public/assets #{user}@#{server.host}:#{shared_path}/"
      end
    end
  end
end
```